# Can't compile image with `gforthmi`

Tags: forth, gforth

The application shown below

```
." Hello, world!"
bye
```

creates the following error when compiling via `gforthmi stdout.4th`:

```
/usr/bin/gforthmi: 47: /usr/bin/gforthmi: /usr/lib/gforth/0.7.3/gforth-ditc: not found
/usr/bin/gforthmi: 48: /usr/bin/gforthmi: /usr/lib/gforth/0.7.3/gforth-ditc: not found
redefined th  
*OS command line*:-1: No such file or directory
comp-image >>>./temp-image.fi1<<< ./temp-image.fi2 stdout.4th bye
Backtrace:
$7F416215C970 throw 
$7F41621924F8 slurp-file 
rm: cannot remove './temp-image.fi1': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove './temp-image.fi2': No such file or directory
```

I am running `gforth 0.7.3` installed on an Ubuntu system via the official Ubuntu PPA.

Have I made a mistake in the way I compile the image? Am I missing any options?

Comment: I couldn't make it work when I tried, so I don't have a real answer. I think it is partly using the form `gforthmi stdout.fi stdout.4th` (the first parameter is the ***output*** file so the input file stdout.4th is *destroyed* (overwritten) if using the form in the question) and partly setting the environment variable `GFORTHD` (e.g. `export GFORTHD=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gforth/0.7.0/gforth-ditc` on Raspberry Pi). However, this is not enough. I really don't know what to do with `savesystem` word mentioned in *[13.5.1 gforthmi](http://www.hep.by/gnu/gforth/gforthmi.html)*.

Comment: `gforthmi` is a shell script (text file) and is e.g. in `/usr/bin/gforthmi` (located with `which gforthmi`). It may or may not help to take a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's couple of issues involved.

For some reason `gforth-ditc` on ubuntu is located in different path. Not under `/usr/bin`, but under `/use/lib/$MACHTYPE/gforth/$version`. I.e. for 64-bit ubuntu and gforth version 0.7.2 I have it located at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gforth/0.7.2/gforth-ditc`. Find it in your system and specify with `GFORTHD` environment variable.

Second problem is with your test sample. It shouldn't end with `bye`, as that will terminate `gforth-ditc` (used by `gforthmi`) without possibly saving anything, as  `savesystem` word passed as arguments to `gforth-ditc` will never be reached.

Another hint - your test sample will be interpreted during compilation, but won't contribute any code to generated image. At least define some words to be called after your image is loaded :)